# MariaDB Stored Procedure gets stuck in a loop matching on the same Join row

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, mariadb

I have a requirement to match rows across two tables. Once a match was made I remove the rows matched and proceed to keep matching the subsequent matches.

My Stored Procedure works up until a certain match and then it iterates on that same match until my while loop hits it's row limit. I set this row limit because the SP previously looped infinitely.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE MatchTransactions()
BEGIN
    -- Declare variables at the beginning
    DECLARE rows_deleted INT DEFAULT 1;
    DECLARE min_rows INT;

    -- Create temporary tables
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE TempA AS SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS row_num FROM SA_A;
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE TempB AS SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS row_num FROM SA_B;

    -- Get the minimum number of rows between the two tables
    SELECT LEAST((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TempA), (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TempB)) INTO min_rows;

    -- Create a table to store the matches
    CREATE TABLE Matches (A_row INT, B_row INT, A_ID INT, B_ID INT);


    -- Loop until no more matches are found or the number of iterations exceeds the minimum number of rows
    WHILE rows_deleted > 0 AND (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Matches) < min_rows DO
        -- Reset rows_deleted
        SET rows_deleted = 0;

        -- Start a new transaction
        START TRANSACTION;

        -- Find a match
        SELECT A.row_num, B.row_num, A.A_ID, B.B_ID INTO @match_A, @match_B, @A_id, @B_id
        FROM TempA AS A
        INNER JOIN TempB AS B 
        ON A.ENTRY_DATE = B.TRANSACTION_DATE 
        AND A.TRANSACTION_AMOUNT = B.TRANSACTION_AMOUNT 
        AND A.CREDIT_DEBIT = B.CREDIT_DEBIT 
        AND A.ACCOUNT = B.PRIMARY_ACCOUNT 
        AND ABS(TIMEDIFF(A.TIME, B.TIME)) <= '00:00:15'
        LIMIT 1;

        -- If a match was found, delete it from both tables and add it to the Matches table
        IF @A_id IS NOT NULL AND @B_id IS NOT NULL THEN
            DELETE FROM TempA WHERE A_ID = @A_id;
            DELETE FROM TempB WHERE B_ID = @B_id;

            INSERT INTO Matches(A_row, B_row, A_ID, B_ID) VALUES (@match_A, @match_B, @A_id, @B_id);

            -- Get the number of rows deleted in this iteration
            SET rows_deleted = ROW_COUNT();
        END IF;

        -- Commit the transaction
        COMMIT;
    END WHILE;

    -- Select the matches
    SELECT * FROM Matches;

    -- Drop the temporary tables and the Matches table
    DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS TempA;
    DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS TempB;
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Matches;
END//
DELIMITER ;
```

As stated before I added the min_rows constraint on the WHILE loop to force it's termination and anyways the theoretical max rows in my Matches table should at best be equal to min_rows.

Answer (score 0):

When the match was found you delete it from the both source tables, and add it to a `Matches` table. Thats correct, but what happens when there are some rows that cant be matched, so the while condition `(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Matches) < min_rows` is always fullfilled?

If such a scenario happen, it will never have the number of the rows inside `Matches` table that is atleast equal to variable `min_rows`- so it keeps running infinitely.

Maybe you should decrease that value of a variable `min_rows` when a match is not found ?

And the reason for `getting stuck on the same row` perfectly confirms what im talking about. Stored procedure cant find a match for that row, so it keeps running because result of `(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Matches) < min_rows` is `TRUE`.

Comment: min_rows is the only reason the WHILE loop stops. I put it as a kill switch to stop the WHILE loop. The min_rows works as intended. The issue is with  rows_deleted. For some reason it is always > 0. Another unusual thing is that at a certain point through the iterations the same exact match gets written indefinitely into table Matches. I want  rows_Deleted to work as intended and fully remove min_rows from my procedure.

Comment: @mouse_s Then im not able to reproduce this issue at my side. Your code is "trying to reinvent the wheel" that already exist (you should consider Charlieface's answer and edit it to your needs), but your code seems to be correct. I see no reason of infinite loop here. Or maybe you didnt share everything with us. Consider reviewing triggers, locks, or other aspects of your database logic that might be affecting the result.

Comment: Charlieface's answer unfortunately doesn't work. I can demonstrate it with a simple example. The issue is the TIMEDIFF(). Suppose TABLE_A has a row 1 with time 13:00:00 and TABLE_B has row 1 11:00:00 and row 2 13:00:05 and they are partitioned. In TABLE_B row 1 and row 2 are identical except for time where only row 2 matches with row 1 from TABLE_A but since I partitioned it does not allign as a match for TABLE_A.

Comment: @mouse_s sorry, but i guess i cannot come up with any other ideas. As i said, your code seems to be correct. An issue needs to be somewhere else, but im not able to point it out based on current info.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't need a loop at all. When you find yourself reaching for loops and cursor in SQL, rethink what you are doing because you are probably barking up the wrong tree.

You can just do a joined `DELETE`.

```sql
DELETE A, B
FROM TempA AS A
INNER JOIN TempB AS B 
   ON A.ENTRY_DATE = B.TRANSACTION_DATE 
  AND A.TRANSACTION_AMOUNT = B.TRANSACTION_AMOUNT 
  AND A.CREDIT_DEBIT = B.CREDIT_DEBIT 
  AND A.ACCOUNT = B.PRIMARY_ACCOUNT 
  AND ABS(TIMEDIFF(A.TIME, B.TIME)) <= '00:00:15';
```

If the join gives multiple matches, and you only want to match an equal number of rows from both sides then you can row-number both sides, partitioning by the join conditions, and then join by row-number.

```sql
DELETE A, B
FROM (
    SELECT *,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY A.ENTRY_DATE, A.TRANSACTION_AMOUNT, A.CREDIT_DEBIT, A.ACCOUNT ORDER BY A.TIME) AS rn
    FROM TempA AS A
) A
INNER JOIN  (
    SELECT *,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY A.ENTRY_DATE, A.TRANSACTION_AMOUNT, A.CREDIT_DEBIT, A.ACCOUNT ORDER BY B.TIME) AS rn
    FROM TempB AS B
) B
   ON A.ENTRY_DATE = B.TRANSACTION_DATE 
  AND A.TRANSACTION_AMOUNT = B.TRANSACTION_AMOUNT 
  AND A.CREDIT_DEBIT = B.CREDIT_DEBIT 
  AND A.ACCOUNT = B.PRIMARY_ACCOUNT 
  AND ABS(TIMEDIFF(A.TIME, B.TIME)) <= '00:00:15'
  AND A.rn = B.rn;
```

Comment: I'm not interested in the DELETE. I need the matched rows. Each matched row needs to be used only once from each table.

Comment: For Example if in TABLE A row 1 matches with row 1,2 and 3 in TABLE B. Then whichever match happens first is counted and removed from further matching. So for instance 1 - 1 gets matched they are no more available for other matches.